# How to limit an access for views in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2013

How to limit an access for views in Sharepoint 2013 ? If a user go to the link mysite.com/SitePages, he will be redirected to mysite.com/SitePages/Forms/AllPages.aspx and can edit or delete my pages. How to fix it ? If i set a permissions for document library, he can't open any pages in this library.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to delete all the permissions about this library.
Then you add Read only permission to all users.

1- Go to SitePages
2- In the ribbon click Library/Library Settings
3- Click "Permission for this document library" (Sorry my sharepoint is not in english the name may be a little different)
4- Break permission inheritance
5- Select all permissions and remove them all.
6- Click on the button to add a new permission 
7- Choose "All authenticated users" and select the "Read" permission
8- Click "share"